# GFCI protection on a shower light

Tags: wiring, bathroom-fixtures

[image: drawing of how I have it wired - should this work]I am adding a light/fan inside a shower. I would like to add GFCI protection. I have a standard circuit and thought I could simply take the line to a GFCI outlet, then take the load to the switch, switch to light. But when I do the GFCI won't work. I get no power to light or outlet. when I press the reset it immediately trips.

Switch is a standard switch where the hot load from GFCI is going to bottom on the switch and the top black is going to the light. White wires from light and load from GFI are twisted and capped. Ground wires from GFCI  and light are twisted.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you wired everything correctly, and that your GFCI isn't actually tripping for good reason?

Comment: Also, does the white from the switch go to the load of the GFCI, or is it tied to the neutral feeding the GFCI?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to show us some connection photos. Something's not right.

Comment: White wire from gfi is twisted to the white wire coming from light. I thought I had the wiriing right because I replaced the GFI outlets with a standard one and ittested as correct no open ground, neutral or hot. I tried 3 different GFIs to just to be sure.. If you are saying it should have worked then I am going to take everything apart and try again.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. "Try rewiring until it works" has a very real chance of getting you killed or starting a fire. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Is this a switch leg where there is a black wire on one terminal of the switch and a black wire on the other terminal?

Comment: On regular receps, the extra screws are just extra terminals for *whatever*.  Do you think the same of GFCI LOAD terminals?  What is connected to LOAD neutral?

Comment: yes the switch is the type with two 1 black on one terminal and the other terminal has the other black wire. (Black = hot) - White/neutral is on the load side of GFI and it twisted to the white wire coming from the light into the switch box. When I get off work today I will take pictures. - thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The diagram above is nearly correct and when I wired it that way the light AND connected the ground to the ground on the switch (rather than capping it) it worked and when I tested the GFI the light went out.. thanks.